# Race condition with Liquibase acquiring changelog lock with Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, liquibase

I’m having a strange issue when attempting to apply changelog updates to an Azure CosmosDB instance emulating the Cassandra API. When applying the updates, Liquibase attempts to get a lock in the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table. I have verified there is no lock prior to this. But instead of acquiring the lock, it gets into a loop waiting for the changelog lock. However, I can see that a lock was granted to this update process at the very timestamp of the first message “Waiting for changelog lock…”

Here’s the lock:

```
id | locked | lockgranted                     | lockedby
----+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------
  1 |   True | 2023-07-21 16:04:12.196000+0000 | 58ee50fd8429 (x.x.x.x)
```

And here is the output from the update operation with log-level=INFO:

```
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | Starting Liquibase at 16:04:09 (version 4.21.1 #9070 built at 2023-04-13 20:56+0000)
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:09] INFO [liquibase.ui] Starting Liquibase at 16:04:09 (version 4.21.1 #9070 built at 2023-04-13 20:56+0000)
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | Liquibase Version: 4.21.1
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:09] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Version: 4.21.1
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | Liquibase Open Source 4.21.1 by Liquibase
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:09] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Open Source 4.21.1 by Liquibase
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:09] INFO [liquibase.integration] Starting command execution.
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:12] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:22] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:32] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:42] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:04:53] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:05:03] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:05:13] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
clm-dev-liquibase-cassandra  | [2023-07-21 16:05:23] INFO [liquibase.ext] Waiting for changelog lock....
```

Notice the timestamp of the lock in the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table is the same as the first “Waiting for changelog lock…” message. The issue doesn’t happen all the time. Running the “release-locks” command clears the lock fine, but it will happen again with the next update.

Because this is CosmosDB emulating Cassandra, I’m using the Simba JDBC driver for Cassandra, not the CosmosDB driver. This works fine on true Cassandra databases. I’m only having the issue on Azure CosmosDB instances emulating Cassandra.

Anyone see this issue and know what to do about it?

Comment: It appears from "SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation" that an error being returned by Cassandra API is being swallowed in your app. This is not a known error, best to raise a support case. In the interim, I suggest trying the native Cassandra driver instead of the JDBC one, if possible. You may also want to consider using Azure Managed Instance for Apache Cassandra for 100% compatibility - this is built by Cosmos DB team but is 100% compatible with Apache Cassandra: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/managed-instance-apache-cassandra/introduction

Comment: Thanks @TheovanKraay. I found that I have been using the 4.21.1 version of the liquibase-cassandra extension, and looking at the code for the latest 4.23.1 version, there is logic to address what I'm seeing, where it checks to see if the lock is held by the current process requesting the lock. It wasn't quite enough, so I extended the check for current process on each iteration of attempts to acquire the lock. Problem solved.